# java correctness of override abstract method

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

Given the following:

```
public class RegistryIdModel extends AbstractTableModel{
     ContactExtensionProviderLocal provider;
     .
     .
     .
    @Override
    public ContactRegistryIdProviderLocal getProvider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return provider;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractTableModel extends AbstractModel{
    public abstract MutableEntityProvider getProvider();
}

public interface ContactRegistryIdProviderLocal extends MutableEntityProvider<EppContactRegistryId>  {
....some methods....
}
```

***Is it a good/bad solution to let the
method in RegistryIdModel to Override
the return type to a
ContactRegistryProviderLocal?***

If I do this, it makes my life easier but what might the effects be later on?

Tanks for any help or helpful comments!
Marthin

Comment: Exactly how is the interface `ContactExtensionProviderLocal` related to `ContactRegistryIdProviderLocal`? Is `ContactRegistryIdProviderLocal` an implementation of `ContactExtensionProviderLocal`?

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015055/java-error-return-type-is-incompatible/6015073#6015073). It is somewhat related to what you are asking.

Comment: Didn't it give you the compilation error : 'incompatible types .. '?

Comment: @phuibers my apologize. Its now fixed. I hade copied the wrong code from eclipse.

Comment: Does `ContactRegistryIdProviderLocal` inherits from `MutableEntityProvider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override the return type. You can only provide (or specify) narrow implementation. This is called covariant return types (since Java 5). For example

```
abstract class A {
    abstract Serializable getId();
}

abstract class B extends A {
    @Override
    abstract Number getId();
}

class C extends B {

    @Override
    Integer getId() {
        return 42;
    }

}
```

Comment: Up for clarification of terminology and the correct answer: 42.

Answer (score 3):

`ContactExtensionProviderLocal` is-a `MutableEntityProvider`, so that means as long as it continues to function as a `MutableEntityProvider` in other parts of your system that don't know anything about a `ContactExtensionProviderLocal`, you've used OO principles well and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the subtype that you're using complies with the specified interface, you should be ok. In this scenario, it would comply since you're extending the parent interface.

On another note, if all your specific implementations need to return specific types, I would question the need to include this method in your base (abstract) class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A quick reply for the reason is that i have many classes that extend the AbstractTableView and they all come to a time when they need to get the hold of a Container that holds the correct type of entities in it so I want to force implementing classes to provid this functionalite since I have many different containers and entities. This will help me in the future so I dont forget about it, perhaps that part could be done by a interface though but I also have many other methods in the abstract class so at this time it was simply easier.

Comment: Another option would be to genericize and use the generic parameter as the return type. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, overriding the return type to return a subclass is fine. You still fulfill the contract specified by `AbstractTableModel`.

Note that this will only work in Java 1.5 or above. Java 1.4 does not support covariant return types.