# Incompatible return Type Error in java

Tags: java

So I have a two classes like following

```
public abstract class BaseFoo{
   protected abstract GetModel getModel();
}

public class HybridBaseFoo extends BaseFoo {
    @Override
    protected HybridGetModel getModel() { // error here
    }

}
```

Where HybridGetModel has following relationship

```
public abstract class AbstractGetModel{
}

public class GetModel extends AbstractGetModel{

}

public class HybridGetModel extends GetModel{
}
```

But I am getting `The return type is incompatible with BaseFoo.getModel()` where i have indicated in the code the error.

Comment: You can not have a method with different return types and same name and parameterlist

Comment: @Jens But HybridGetModel extends GetModel. I thought we could do that?

Comment: @Jens: You should be able to narrow return types in subclasses.

Comment: "The sub class cannot declare a method with the same name of an already existing method in the super class with a different return type." see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015055/java-error-return-type-is-incompatible

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type this should be legal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Error : return type is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015055/java-error-return-type-is-incompatible)

Comment: What is your java version? In java 8 it seems to work (with a `return null;`)

Comment: Maybe the error is misleading (and it just complains about you not returning anything)?

Comment: In my case @Thilo was right, there was a problem with superclass resolution, but Eclipse IDE's compiler shown "The return type is incompatible" error. I've fixed classpath and the error is gone

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can recreate your error is by returning the wrong type of object from the getModel method

For example this works fine:

```
public class HybridBaseFoo extends BaseFoo {
    @Override
    protected HybridGetModel getModel() {
        return new HybridGetModel();
    }
}
```

but this gives the error `incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to HybridGetModel`:

```
public class HybridBaseFoo extends BaseFoo {
    @Override
    protected HybridGetModel getModel() {
        return ""; //error here
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get if you leave off the `return` line altogether?

Comment: @Thilo: `missing return statement`

Answer (score 0):

You could return `GetModel`:

```
public class HybridBaseFoo extends BaseFoo {
    @Override
    protected GetModel getModel() {
      return new HybridGetModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting? Please leave a comment so I could learn something from your sageness.

Comment: it should be possible to return a HybridGetModel object