# error with the return type - The return type is incompatible

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, error-handling, syntax

Here is my code. I have written this method return the dominant point of the shape. min,max 2 points (left-low, right-up). But I  got an error with the return value please see my method here:

```
@Override
public Point2D[] getPoints() {
    Point2D[] ans = new Point2D[2];
    if (this._point1.getX()<=this._point2.getX()) {
        ans[0] =new Point2D(this._point1);
        ans[1] =new Point2D(this._point2);
    }
    else{
        ans[0] =new Point2D(this._point2);
        ans[1] =new Point2D(this._point1);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

and here is the class `Point2D`:

```
public class Point2D implements GeoShape{
public static final double EPS1 = 0.001, EPS2 = Math.pow(EPS1,2), EPS=EPS2;
public static final Point2D ORIGIN = new Point2D(0,0);
private double _x,_y;
public Point2D(double x,double y) {
    _x=x; _y=y;
}
public Point2D(Point2D p) {
   this(p.x(), p.y());
}
public Point2D(String s) {
    try {
        String[] a = s.split(",");
        _x = Double.parseDouble(a[0]);
        _y = Double.parseDouble(a[1]);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("ERR: got wrong format string for Point2D init, got:"+s+"  should be of format: x,y");
        throw(e);
    }
}
public double x() {return _x;}
public double y() {return _y;}
public double getX() {return _x;}
public double getY() {return _y;}

public int ix() {return (int)_x;}
public int iy() {return (int)_y;}

public Point2D add(Point2D p) {
    Point2D a = new Point2D(p.x()+x(),p.y()+y());
    return a;
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return _x+","+_y;
}

public double distance()
{
    return this.distance(ORIGIN);
}
public double distance(Point2D p2)
{
    double dx = this.x() - p2.x();
    double dy = this.y() - p2.y();
    double t = (dx*dx+dy*dy);
    return Math.sqrt(t);
}
```

I have an error with the return for this method `getpoints`. Check this image:

[image: here is the error message]

The return type is incompatible with `GeoShape.getPoints()`.

Anybody have an idea what cause that?

Comment: `GeoShape` is an interface, what is the signature of `getPoints` method in this interface?

Comment: Image not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015055/java-error-return-type-is-incompatible

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @Override
> public Point2D[] getPoints() {
> ```
>
> The return type is incompatible with GeoShape.getPoints()

Whatever class this is in, it `implements GeoShape`. And GeoShapes must have the `Rectange getPoints()` method. Or whatever it might be - a getPoints method that returns something particular, and the particular thing is not a supertype of `Point2D[]` - you did not paste it.

1. All apples are fruit. All (Whatever that Point2D[] getPoints() method is in) is a GeoShape.
2. GeoShapes have a `getPoints()` method that returns a Rectangle.
3. I can treat your (whatever that is) as a GeoShape.
4. Therefore your (whatever that is) must have a `Rectangle getPoints()` method.
5. But it doesn't, therefore, compiler error.

The fix would be to either [A] stop implementing `GeoShape`, [B] change GeoShape's `getPoints` method to return `Point2D[]` instead, or [C] change the return type of your getPoints method to match the return type of the getPoints method in GeoShape.